# Should I report broken ads?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, advertising

I just saw the following ad on StackOverflow:

[image: Firefox ad]

It looked interesting, so I clicked on it and got a 404:

[image: 404]

It looked like one of those "support-community-open-source-projects" ads, so I felt like I should I report this. I noticed the thumb up/thumb down icons in the upper right-hand corner, but none of the thumb down options applied.

Should I report this? If yes, to whom?

Comment: Nope, it's not an open source ad, since it does not appear [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260377/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2014). It's a full-fledged ad bought with money, SE should inform them that it's broken.

Comment: Stevvve already fixed it all up, but to answer your question: yes, please report things like this. Here on meta is a good place to do so. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @shadowwizard pointed out-- no, these are not open source ads.

That said-- all fixed!

Thank you for the heads up!